# How to make sure script executes completely before executing?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script which is containing some queries:

```
$id    = $_GET['id'];
$value = $_GET['val'];

// database connection here

// inserting
$stm1 = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT into table1 (col) VALUES (?)");
$stm1->execute(array($value));

// updating
$stm2 = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE table2 SET col = "a new row inserted" WHERE id = ?");
$stm2->execute(array($id));
```

As you see there is two statements (`insert` and `update`). All I'm trying to do is making sure both of them work or none of them.

I mean I want to implement a dependency between those two statements. If updating fails, then inserting shouldn't work and vice versa. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transactions and PDO has an api for this (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php),

```
$id    = $_GET['id'];
$value = $_GET['val'];

// database connection here

try{
    $db_conn->beginTransaction();
    // inserting
    $stm1 = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT into table1 (col) VALUES (?)");
    $stm1->execute(array($value));

    // updating
    $stm2 = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE table2 SET col = "a new row inserted" WHERE id = ?");
    $stm2->execute(array($id));

    $db_conn->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $db_conn->rollBack();
}
```

Comment: Beginning the transaction is missing :) Also, the storage engine must support it (MyISAM does not)

Comment: @GerardvanHelden The storage engine must support what? `BEGIN TRAN` *(in mysql query)* or `rollBack()` function in php?

Comment: @engvrdr My storage is innodb, just I want to know, what thing doesn't work on myisam ?

Comment: @stack MyISAM does not support transactions (it is a non-transactional engine), so if your storage engine is innoDB this should work as expected.

Comment: ok, thank you .. upvote .. Just to be clear, what do you mean *transactines*? Is that `beginTransaction()` *(in PHP)* or `BEGIN TRAN` *(in MySQL)*?

Comment: it is same actually pdo's beginTransaction method basically does the same thing you would do when you are writing this on a mysql client. 

BEGIN TRAN also will not work on a table with a storage engine MyISAM this is not the limitation of php or PDO it is a limitation by the database layer.

To get a better knowledge about transactions you can check here : http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3382171/Transactions-in-MySQL.htm

Comment: I see, so using `beginTransaction()` function is the same as writing `BEGIN TRAN` in the beginning of the query, right?

Answer (score 2):

You could use sql transactions
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for not writing the whole statement and just providing the link with the name of the method you would need to use. I think that even if this link will stop working in the future people still can google sql transactions and find tons of tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, you could use 'transactions'.

Or
you could mannualy check whether the data is right in the database. Just 'select' what you have inserted.

The 'execute' function return 'true' on success or 'false' on failure. You can do something like:

```
$isDone=$stm1->execute(array($value));

if(!$isDone){
    echo 'Operation fails, I will stop.';
    return false;

}
```